# CakePHP retrieving User model but default no password returned

Tags: php, cakephp

I am writing an API that returns all Users that fit a certain criteria and their associated models in JSON format.

My question is--how do I make it automatically not return the hashed password field when returning the user data to the client who is getting my JSON data? This seems like it should be a standard problem, but without using contain/fields, can I make it so that the default behavior is it does not return the hashed password whenever I do a simple find?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the models [`afterFind()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1050/afterFind) to remove the password from the result set like so:

```
public function afterFind($results = array(), $primary) {
    foreach($results as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($results[$key][$this->modelAlias]['password'])) {
            unset($results[$key][$this->modelAlias]['password']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use isset() first to avoid notices in case there is no password key in the data!

Comment: @mark very true, although with Auth there will always be a password key, even if the password was blank

Comment: Don't you need to return `$results` at the end?

Answer (score 4):

I tend to do this in a `beforeFind()` so that a request *can* be made to include the password:

```
public function beforeFind( $query ) {
  # Don't return the password field unless it's specified.
  $query['fields'] = empty( $query['fields'] )
    ? array_diff( array_keys( $this->schema() ), array( 'password' ) )
    : $query['fields'];

  return $query;
}
```

This way, I don't remove the password if it was explicitly specified (there are times when this is useful), but do in every other case. This solution isn't necessarily any better or worse than the marked answer, but does offer a bit of flexibility that I've found useful.

Comment: Great solution!! In addition to being more performant, this HAS to be more performant than looping over every record in `afterFind()`

Comment: @Rob I found one issue: If the find has associated models joined, this will strip those out. Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: @SDP Can you be more specific about what you mean?

Comment: @RobWilkerson For example, if Containable is used to return results from multiple models at once, then ALL (or none) of the fields have to be listed for it to work. As written, we replace the original (blank) query with only the fields of the current model's schema. Effectively wiping out the associated model data. Make sense?

Comment: Yep. That's definitely an issue with this example. You'd probably have to inspect the `$query` in your case and make the update more surgical.